# Entity Framework Core Key attribute error to call procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core.

I have a problem with the data model when trying to call a SQL Server procedure.

`FromSql` method to bind data model is not working if I do not set `Key` attribute.

This is my code:

Data model class

```
public class AdminMemberLoginResult
{
    public int AdminIndex { get; set; }
    public string AdminId { get; set; }
    public string AdminName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChangePwd { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class

```
public partial class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public GameContext()
    {
    }

    public GameContext(DbContextOptions<GameContext> dbContextOption) : base(dbContextOption)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data base connection string");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AdminMemberLoginResult> AdminMemberLogin { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<DefaultStatisticsResult> DefaultStatistics { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet of procedure call:

```
var loginResult = _dbContext.Set<AdminMemberLoginResult>()
                      .FromSql("exec Game.dbo.sp_admin_getAdminMemberLogin @p_id, @p_pwd",
                      new SqlParameter("@p_id", id),
                      new SqlParameter("@p_pwd",pwd)).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault();
```

Key attribute error screenshot:

[image: error capture]

How can I use `FromSql` method without `Key` attribute setting in my data model?

Comment: The error **clearly** says: *The entity type ..... **requires** a primary key to be defined.* - it is **required** - so there's no way, no trick around it - just define a viable key!

Comment: What is the reason for not using primary key? From DB point of view, even if not needed, having a primary key column with identity should not affect anything. It is just there to identify each row. Entity Framework need primary key. Sorry for not answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

This question is over a year old, but there didn't seem to be a lot of answers out there.

I Just ran across the same issue and I was able to solve this by changing the DbSet to DbQuery in the DbContext.

This is using dot net core 2.1. There are a couple of different approaches that you can read about here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847184.aspx